# Fitting a monotonically increasing temperature graph with numpy, scikit, python?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have a temperature probe in the middle of a chunk of meat that is heating on a grill that is maintaining a (roughly) fixed temperature.  I'd like to model the extrapolated heating curve and predict the temperature at the probe N minutes in the future.  I'm trying to use numpy's polyfit to do this but it seems to assume the curve is about to peak and then begin to decrease (see attached image).  How do I correct the model curve to indicate it's actually approaching an asymptote (i.e. the external grill temp)?

I don't want a simple linear model (deg=1, below).  It "works" but is inaccurate because the meat will increase in temperature proportionally to the delta between its current temperature and the outside grill temp (i.e. heating quickly at first and then slowing down as it approaches the external temp)

Here's my non-working code and a graph it produces:

```
def interpolate(X, Y, x):
    poly = np.polyfit(X, Y, deg=2)
    y_pred = np.polyval(poly, x)
    return y_pred

    # ...

plt.ion()
z = list(zip(x, y_probe_temp))
z.reverse()
lasty = None
xs = []
ys = []
for xn, yn in z:
    if lasty is None or yn != lasty:
        xs.insert(0, xn.timestamp())
        ys.insert(0, yn)
        print(f'{xn} => {yn}')
        lasty = yn

print('-----------------------')
print(f'NOW = {now}')
print('-----------------------')
predx = []
predy = []
for m in (2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 60, 90, 120, 180, 360):
    dt = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=m)
    try:
        temp = float(interpolate(xs, ys, dt.timestamp()))
        if temp > 225: #y_grill_setting[-1]:
            temp = 225  #y_grill_setting[-1]
        predx.append(dt)
        predy.append(temp)
        print(f'{dt} => {temp:.1f}F')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
plt.plot(predx, predy, label='extrapolation')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('temp')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
           ncol=4, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

Here's the polynomial it chooses:

[Curve fit by this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNVtR.png)

In reality this probe temp will continue to increase approaching the asymptote of the exterior grill ambient temperature.  What's the best way to model this?  Thanks!

Comment: The curve you're describing is not a 2nd degree polynomial.  You'll never get one that behaves the way you want.  What you're describing is more like hyperbolic tangent.

Comment: Extrapolating polynomials is likely to fail. I guess it will be somewhat like exponential, which seems to be in agreement with [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567370/22717) post. In short: use a fit function that saturates.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  I thought that polyfit would be able to fit a hyperbole type of curve.  I ended up finding this site: https://engineerexcel.com/hyperbolic-curve-fitting-excel/ and digging into how SLOPE and INTERCEPT work in excel.  They use linear regression which I did with sklearn.LinearRegression's coef_ and intercept_ fields.  Then I predicted the next points with the formula from that site and it is reasonably accurate.